# Names on ticket are in different order than on proof of ID - can I still get past airport security?

Tags: bookings

I will be traveling in 15 days on a domestic flight.

My name on the ticket is SECONDNAME FIRSTNAME LASTNAME but on my proof of ID it is like FIRSTNAME SECONDNAME LASTNAME.

Will the security allow me into the airport?
Will there be any problem with the airline people?